# At what level is selection handled in the Cocoa text system?

Tags: cocoa, nstextview

I noticed that if you hook up two NSTextViews to the same NSTextStorage object, you can select across the two and copy/undo/etc. as if they were one. At what level is this all managed? Where should I get the combined selected range from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selection is managed in `NSLayoutManager`. It seems, your two views connected to the same layout manager like on [this picture](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TextArchitecture/Tasks/AssembleSysByHand.html).

If you use more then one layout manager with the text storage, you could get the combined selected range by combining the individual `selectedRanges:` of all the `NSTextView`s.